# Summing all pixels on a Canvas screen?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Attempting to sum the value of all the pixels on canvas:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1280, 720);

var imgData = imageData.data;
    console.log(imgData);
    for(i=0; i<= imgData.length; i++){
        pixelSum = pixelSum + imgData[i];
    }
    alert(pixelSum);
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: No, at least for this: `i<= imgData.length` should be `i< imgData.length` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown will only give the sum of all components, not pixels per-SE.

You do need to change the loop criteria though, as well as declare the `i`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < imgData.length; i++){ ...
```

Also note that this will include the alpha-channel.

If this is for check-summing (comparing images/content against a "fingerprint") then it will be a poor choice as the chance of getting similar sum is much higher than other approaches.  You could use 16-bit or 32-bit wide ranges instead of byte, or more established algorithms such as CRC-32, MD5 and SHA-1/256. It's not clear what you intend to use this for so I leave it with that.